# Is there an adjective related to solidarity?

Tags: single-word-requests

Per Merriam-Webster (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solidarity) the word *solidarity* means

> unity (as of a group or class) that produces or is based on community of interests, objectives, and standards

It comes from French *solidarité* (same meaning) which in turns comes from *solidaire* (characterized by solidarity).

Is there an adjective that means characterized by solidarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the adjective is

> **solidary** 
>   ADJECTIVE
>   (of a group or community) characterized by solidarity or coincidence of interests.
>   [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/solidary)

Not very widely used in English, but so what? It is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Unified
```

Though not etymologically connected to solidarity